# Chrome deleting my unpacked extension folder with every restart

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for Google Chrome and getting my code deleted all the time.

I switched to Google Chrome Dev in order to get rid of the "Developer mode" popup warning, but although that warning has disappeared Google Chrome Dev will delete the extensions folder in the OS every time I restart it. It's weird because it doesn't disable the extension, just deletes the folder, which results in Chrome trying to load missing content for the extension.

Can somebody help me?

I'm using Windows 10 OS + Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.24 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)

Comment: Where is your unpacked extension folder located?

Comment: Do you have a "key" field in the manifest file?

Comment: My unpacked extension folder is located under "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome Dev\User Data\Default\Extensions". "Key" field has some random value from the original manifest file I copied it from.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Xan's comment above I tried moving the unpacked extension to a different local folder such as "C:/Program Files/XYZ" and it has worked ever since. It seems that using Chrome's internal storage extensions folder (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome Dev\User Data\Default\Extensions) was the root cause behind this problem.

Comment: chrome remove extension folder when any directory in the path to extension is a hidden directory

Comment: I put my extension in a totally separate folder under C, yet when chrome failed to load the extension, it simply wiped out my code!!!

Comment: It worked for me too, I use many extension that I have forked and load them as unpacked extension and one of them was removed every time I restarted Chromium.  It's strange since all my unpacked extensions are in the same folder but I've put this extension in another folder on another drives and this time it doesn't disappear on restart..

Answer (score 1):

Same here, as soon I moved the folder where was the extension that was uninstalled on each restart it stopped from being uninstalled.

So after I tried to just change the name of the folder by one letter and strangely it worked too.

My guest is that maybe there was a small bug with this folder and the file system so when I renamed the folder it fixed the problem.

If somebody has the same problem first just try to rename the folder where your extension is located.

Note: I'm under Windows 7.

Comment: I can confirm that renaming the folder works also in Linux! I suspect this is happening after adding "key" field to manifest of unpacked extension which changes extension's "id", especially if the same id has the developed extension added from Chrome Web Store.